# App Service custom backups: which files / directories should be included?

Tags: azure, paas

I am configuring custom backups for my Azure App Service so that I can create lightweight backups just before a deploy that I can use to quickly restore the app if something goes sideways.

The Azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup?tabs=portal#configure-partial-backups) say the following about backups:

> Partial backups are supported for custom backups (not for automatic backups). Sometimes you don't want to back up everything on your app.

From this, it's clear that automatic backups back up the whole file system (with some caveats), and custom backups can filter out certain files and directories using a `_backup.filter` file.

At the moment, I have the following entries in `_backup.filter`:

```
\site\wwwroot\App_Browsers
\site\wwwroot\App_Data
\site\wwwroot\Content
\site\wwwroot\Copyrights
\site\wwwroot\layouts
\site\wwwroot\sitecore
\site\wwwroot\sitecore modules
\site\wwwroot\sitecore_files
\site\wwwroot\static
\site\wwwroot\temp
\site\wwwroot\Views
\site\wwwroot\xsl
\site\wwwroot\_CMP
\site\wwwroot\Global.asax
\site\wwwroot\ApplicationInsights.config
\site\wwwroot\Default.aspx
\site\wwwroot\default.css
\site\wwwroot\default.js
\site\wwwroot\readme.md
\site\wwwroot\webedit.css
```

In my implementation, which is fairly standard, the filters above ensure that only these files and directories are backed up:

- `App_Config`
- `bin`
- `Web.config`

This appears to be a great starting point, given that these frequently change during deploys.

What else should I be considering here? The obvious answer would be to backup anything can change as part of the release process. However, I want to account for any subtleties and gotchas that would be common regardless of the specific implementation. Of particular concern would be `App_Data` and `temp`.

Comment: why not just use deployment slots? That's exactly what they are there for. Zero down time and a super simple rollback.

Comment: also - its this an MVC site or headless? If its MVC, you probably want the `\site\wwwroot\Views` included

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal. It's a headless site. Some of my resistance to using deployment slots is that introduces a scenario in which I'd have 2 instances of the same CM running at the same time. Or are you saying to shut the other slot down and only start it up if needed?

Comment: DM'd you on Slack